# How to send C# properties as parameters at the end of url in window.open method

Tags: c#, javascript

I have one url in which i have to send the some property values. My property like below

```
 public string MyValue
        {
            get { return MyValue; }
            set { MyValue = value; }
        }
```

Now I want to send this value as parameter to the url in window.open method in javascript.

`window.open("../SearchPage/MySearch.aspx?MyValue=","left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500")`
 I tried to access in javascript like 
`'<%= MyValue %>"`.

But this is not coming. It is giving parser error. How to achieve this?

Comment: where does your js located? is it in file ? or in page scripts list?

Comment: I tried with two ways. Kept my .js file in another folder and gave a link to the .aspx file. Another way is directly include the script block in the .aspx file. I writing these properties code behind file of .aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JavaScript is located in a separate file, you can't use `<%= %>` to define variable there, you should use `hidden fields, cookies` and similar stuff

But if you could put js in aspx page, it should work

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('<%= MyProperty %>');
    </script>
</head>
```

This works for me, where MyProperty is public string property in my aspx page, please make sure that you put **quotes** correctly

**EDIT**

Here is my page be

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyProperty = "aaaaaaaaa";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

BTW

```
public string MyValue
{
    get { return MyValue; }
    set { MyValue = value; }
}
```

is not will cause StackOverflowException on set, you should create private variable for storing value :)

```
private string _myValue;
public string MyValue
{
    get { return _myValue; }
    set { _myValue = value; }
}
```

Comment: It is giving following error. `CS0103: The name 'MyValue' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: do you have CodeBehind defined on the page ?

Comment: Yes.. in there only i declaring property. I am declaring in a class

Comment: please try to create a clear application, and try it there, I guess the problem is another place, because as I said it works for me

Comment: If I use Property like `MyProperty{get;set;}` it won't give any error.But if I use like my code sample included in my question block it is giving error `Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.`

Comment: haha, you assign the same variable in your set, create private variable and return it instead of the property, or use auto property as I suggest

Comment: If i give in pageload as `MyValue="Arsen"` will it come in page load? For my case it is not coming.

Comment: Yeah I changed according to your suggestion.After that I checked but not coming as assigned value

Comment: than definitly you put wrong quotes, please drop js you are using

Answer (score 0):

@Mihir: You have used '<%= MyValue %>" which has a single quote in the beginning. Use double quotes in the beginning as well as in the end.

Try this:
**"<%= MyValue %>"**.

Probably it'll work.

You can use Screenfields also to send the values from one page to other.